# How to take backup of Windows server in Linux Server

Tags: backup, windows-server-2012-r2, ubuntu-18.04

we are using a Windows server as the main server in our organization. Now we need to take the backup of that windows server in a Linux machine. Backup is of two types incremental and full backup.
Please, guys, suggest to me how can I set up backup.
Thanks.

Comment: WHat do you mean with "backup of the windows server in a linux machine"?

Comment: I want to take full backup of a windows server and store it in a linux server.

Comment: So? Taking a backup: Solved. Storing files on linux in a means windows can access: solved. What is the problem?

Comment: I want to know how to take the backup, in Linux we can use rsync but in this case, what should I do.

Comment: You need to try something, many ways to do backups. Buy a product, read documentation, modify some (possibly open source) scripts. For opinionated advice customized to your environment, hire a consultant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a backup solution, which can use Linux server as backup repository. Or you can configure CIFS(SMB) on Linux and most of backup solutions can utilise SMB.

For example VEEAM B&R can use Linux repositories - https://helpcenter.veeam.com/docs/backup/hyperv/linux_server.html?ver=95u4